# Calling template method through a pointer to it

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have the next error :

> C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments LINE 33

It fails on calling  the function "param.c1(x)". But why? It seems like it can not deduce the function "c1_1_order_()" taking 1 argument or I do incorrect assignment in the function "config_1_order()".

File "Header.h"

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class TMA {
private:
  double(*p)(double);

  template<class U>
  struct SLAU_params {
  private:
    TMA * obj;

    U c1_1_order_(double x) {
      return  obj->p(x);
    }

    void config_1_order() {
      c1 = &TMA::SLAU_params<U>::c1_1_order_;
    }
  public:
    SLAU_params(TMA * obj) :obj(obj) {
      config_1_order();
    }

    U(TMA::SLAU_params<U>::* c1)(double);
  };
public:
  TMA(double(*p)(double)) :p(p) {}

  template<class U>
  vector<U> TMA_solve(U h) {
    double x = h;
    SLAU_params<U> param(this);
    param.c1(x);
    vector <U> rez;
    return rez;
  }
};
```

"Source.cpp"

```
#include "Header.h"
double p(double x) { return x; }
int main() {
  TMA a(p);
  double h = 1.0;
  a.TMA_solve(h);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. There is no function `c1` in `SLAU_params`.

Comment: There is a pointer to it. C++ usually understand such an invoke, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
param.c1(x);
```

`c1` is a class method pointer. A class method pointer is not a function pointer, it cannot be invoked by itself. A class method pointer must be invoked using either the `.*` or the `->*` operator, on an instance/pointer to the class in question. For example:

```
(param.*(param.c1))(x);
```

Whether or not this the correct application, or whether a different object's method must be invoked through a pointer, like that, is something that you will need to figure out.

There are also other problems with the shown code:

```
 U c1_1_order_(double) {
      return  obj->p(x);
    }
```

The object `x` is not declared here.